# Jquery: Compare input values to array objects and see if they match exactly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

I have 4 inputs, 2 text boxes and 2 radio buttons that I need to get the values of and compare to the objects in array and see if they are an exact match. The four inputs are:

```
<input type="text" id="brand">
<input type="text" id="prodNum">
```

radio 1

```
 <input type="radio" name="radioYN" id="radioY" value="Yes">
 <input type="radio" name="radioYN" id="radioN" value ="No">
```

radio 2

```
<input type="radio" name="radioStock" id="inStock" value="Ship">
<input type="radio" name="radioStock" id="outStock" value="Order">
```

I then take those values and put them in variables

```
var brand=$('input#brand').val();
var prodNum=$('input#prodNum').val();
var radioYN= $("input[name='radioYN']");
var radioStock= $("input[name='radioStock']");
```

All of that works fine, but I don't know how to compare that to the array and see if they match perfectly.Array:

```
 var products = [
 {
  "brand": "brand1",
  "prodNum": "01-005",
  "YN": "Yes",
  "Stock": "Order"
  },
 {
  "brand": "brand2",
  "prodNum": "02-005",
  "YN": "Yes",
  "Stock": "Ship"
  },
 {
  "brand": "brand1",
  "prodNum": "01-008",
  "YN": "No",
  "Stock": "Order"
  }
  ]
```

I'll do and if statement to see if they match

```
  if (inputs == array obeject){
    //do something} 
    else { 
       //do something else}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over items in products array and compare all the fields against the input values. Something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<products.length; i++) {
    var product = products[i];
    if (product.brand === brand && product.prodNum === prodNum && product.YN === radioYN && product.Stock === radioStock) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```